# Will functions I return from closures be available in the outer scope?

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm building a small library after a while away from javascript, and am probably over-thinking this.  I have my library wrapped in a closure, and while I know I can return what I want with something like `window.namespace.function`, I'm wondering if I can more elegantly do something like this:

```
(function($){
  var config = {...}

  var namespace = {
    doStuff: function() {
      // . . .
    },
  }

  return namespace
})(jQuery)
```

After this script has loaded, will a user be able to call my library with something like `namespace.doStuff()`?

Also, if a user simply copied and pasted my library within a closure of their own, would my namespace then be available within their closure, but not as a global?

Comment: no, you need to publish your namepace to a var via the return, or to a global

Comment: @dandavis What's the difference between doing what you're saying and my `return namespace`?

Comment: starting with var myObj=(function($){  ... or assign window.xxx inside, or use a module system like commonJS to modify a pseudo-global like _exports_

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I knew I was over-thinking it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would only be available in the outer scope if you assign it to something.  As it is you are returning it, but not assigning it to anything so it is then not available.

You could assign it like this:

```
var ns = (function($){
  var config = {...}

  var namespace = {
    doStuff: function() {
      // . . .
    },
  }

  return namespace;
})(jQuery);
```

Then, you could call the `doStuff()` function from the outer scope like this:

```
ns.doStuff();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I was missing something really basic like that.  Do you know if it would be hoisted?